# Contactor vs. Breaker-type Automatic Transfer Switches

Tags: power, protection

What is the difference between a contactor-type and a circuit breaker-type automatic transfer switch?

See example products at [Eaton.com](http://www.eaton.com/Electrical/USA/ProductsandServices/ElectricalDistribution/ATS/index.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the link. I edited my original post because it is now clear what you are looking for.

EDIT:
The circuit breaker type uses actual circuit breakers to do the transfer switching. This offers additional overload protection. A simple contactor type of transfer only switches the load from each source of power, not offering any over current protection. Additional protection must be in place upstream of the switch.

In either type a load study should be done to ensure proper load shedding, which includes upstream protection for either type. You did not offer any insight as to what this is for, but if it is for industrial applications then it is common practice for a PE Engineer to approve such a load study before the job is contracted out.

Answer (score 1):

Circuit-breakers are mechanical spring-loaded things.

Contactors are electrically-driven high-power or high-voltage relays (where "high"-x is residential service panel type voltages/powers; utilities consider high voltage at 10s of kilovolts). They are turned on/off electronically. We have one in a project at work that's about the size/shape of a small juice can, looks kind of like the one on [this webpage](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?SKU=41T2129&CMP=AFC-GB100000001):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Both are used for making & breaking the circuits. 
Contactor basically used for open/close the circuit with n/o and n/c contacts. Contactor making and breaking circuits but circuit breakers making and breaking circuit with sufficient short circuit rating level for safe process.